# how to add user-agent string from Android for RESTFul web Service monitoring?

Tags: android, web-services, user-agent

I am having Restful service for my application and many of the user are utilizing it. Now I would like to monitor the service as I am having free as well as paid version of the app. SO I would like to add the user-agent string at the time of call of web service; like for free app let say **FREE, 1.0** and for paid **Premium, 1.0**.

How can i add the user-agent string from my android application? If anyone has any idea please kindly guide me.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have got so far?

Comment: No i don't have and i don't have any idea on this that's why i asked the question. There is no meaning of down vote who so ever has down voted. If somebody can't give suggestion than kindly don't show off reputation power by downvoting...still no issue as its a public forum for...we are here to help each other i think...

Comment: Yea,  typically on stackoverflow there are rules against asking questions without code or expressing effort. Its a good read, and overall, it will help you more in the long term in learning (not just getting) solutions on here.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a request, use the addHeader method to add whatever header you want to it

```
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/api/resource");
    request.addHeader("User-Agent", "MY-CUSTOM-USER-AGENT");
```